# How to fix encoding issue without rewriting the text again?

Tags: asp.net, html, encoding, metadata, arabic

I face the following problem :

I have an .aspx page when i copy a gridview from page to another ,i encounter the following problem :

i have some arabic words like this :

```
رقم اذن الإضافة
```

It has turned to :

```
&#1585;&#1602;&#1605; &#1575;&#1584;&#1606; &#1575;&#1604;&#1573;&#1590;&#1575;&#1601;&#1577;
```

---

My master page meta data :

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

How to fix this problem

all arabic data have turned to those strange characters and numbers!! just in design time

,However in run time every thing goes okay .

But when i try to edit , i take a lot of time to detect the right control !
How to fix this problem without rewriting all these arabic characters again ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use UTF-8 or Windows-1256 encoding for it to show properly, see for example [What character encoding should I use for a web page containing mostly Arabic text? Is utf-8 okay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996475/what-character-encoding-should-i-use-for-a-web-page-containing-mostly-arabic-tex)

Comment: if i change the metadata to `UTF-8 or Windows-1256` the data will change to the correct one automatically ?

Comment: the probelm is in design time not on runtime

Comment: It can be a little tricky when encoding is inconsistent in the workflow. I recommend using the same encoding through the whole process. Sometimes I just open my standard texteditor and resaves the script file with the correct encoding. If you have an aspx file saved with ISO-8859-1 it will not recognize the contents correctly if you paste in data with for example UTF-8 encoding, or the other way round. You might also have the file saved as Windows-1256 but then showed as ISO (from your META tag). It will affect design but not runtime...

Comment: Thanks a lot .`It will affect design but not runtime`
but how to fix the design time without writing from the scratch with the correct encoding

Comment: Hello again. If you encounter problems that encoding is working in some situation but not in another then there IS encoding inconsistency in your workflow. Find the anomaly and your problem is solved!