# How to display Arabic word in java server page?

Tags: jsp, arabic

I am creating a simple web application using *Eclipse Kit* in *java*. I need to display the Arabic word into a java server page.

In my web application, I am able to store the Arabic language into my database (MYSQL) and then retrieve from that database using a jdbc template (spring framework), but i could not display the Arabic word into my webpage, which means java server page.

My Environment:

1. Java 1.7
2. Tomcat 7.0 server
3. Eclipse Juno version
4. Mysql

Can anyone help me resolving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the proper character encoding [utf8 or utf16](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2996528/1113392)

In your JSP you need to insert the page directive for the encoding

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="utf-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h2>ا ب ت ث ج ح خ د ذ ر ز س ش ص ض ط ظ ع غ ف ق ك ل م ن ه و ي</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

In a Servlet you need to set the content type in the response object

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain; charset=utf-8");
    PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
    writer.write("ا ب ت ث ج ح خ د ذ ر ز س ش ص ض ط ظ ع غ ف ق ك ل م ن ه و ي");
}
```

Note that if you have String literals containing arabic letter then the file also has to be saved in `utf8` or `utf16`

Answer (score 1):

you need to set http response encoding style UTF8

like...

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

Also see this article for more Reference [here](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#JSPServletResponse)

try this code may help you.