# How to write inside a text file using arabic letters with the accents? Java

Tags: java, unicode, netbeans, arabic

I have a problem with `Netbeans` file viewer. I have a string in Arabic that includes accents in top of each letter. When I remove the accents from the string, the letters display correctly. However, when I write the string with the accents, it gets somehow disordered (incorrect).

This is an example of what is happening:

- Text without accents (correct): `بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم`
- Text with accents (incorrect): `it shows broken, but if i copy it here it prints correctly`
- It should be like this (correct): `بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ`

The code I wrote is to read a text file that includes an arabic string along with its accents, then write it correctly in a new file, then at the end, it deletes the old file. This is the code:

```java
public void arabicReformer(File disordered) {
    File output = new File("data/temp2.txt");

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(disordered), "UTF8"));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(output), "UTF8"));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            bw.write(line.trim() + "\n");
        }
        br.close();
        bw.close();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    output.renameTo(disordered);
}
```

PS: when I copy past the incorrect arabic string with the accents here, it prints correctly!

Comment: Did you try with other encoding, UTF-16 for example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996475/what-character-encoding-should-i-use-for-a-web-page-containing-mostly-arabic-tex may be?

Comment: Did you ensure, that your input file is in UTF8 too?

Comment: Unicode can represent an accented letter as one (integrated) symbol, letter-with-accent or two: letter without accent, and zero-width accent. `java.text.Normalizer` can convert between them. I think letter+accent causes the representation bug. Create a bug report. Maybe RTL/LTR controls already solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Good Day my Friend :)
Try using this code to read and print Arabic Characters, and try ensuring that your file is originally in UTF-8.

```
public void unicodeShow(String fileName) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), "utf-8");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String a=br.readLine();
    System.out.println(a);
}
```