# Php mail not sending arabic letters

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I have php code to send email in arabic but it is not working.

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: DAC ";
$message .= '<html><body>';
$message .= '<table width="100%";>';
$message .= "<tr><td><img src='http://dgf.com/images/logo.png' alt='http://dacthatsmymom.com/' /></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='height:10px;border:none'><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td colspan=2>Dear, Admin<br /><br />

<strong>Person Contact Detail: </strong><br/>
<strong>Name: </strong>".trim($_POST['name'])."<br/>
<strong>Email: </strong>".trim($_POST['email'])."<br/>
<strong>City #: </strong>".trim($_POST['city'])."<br/>
<strong>Address #: </strong>".trim($_POST['address'])."<br/>
<strong>Country#: </strong>".trim($_POST['country'])."<br/>
<strong>Selected Card#: </strong><a href='$cardimage'>Card Image</a><br/>
</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td colspan=2 font='colr:#999999;'><br/><br/><strong><I>Dac<br>System Generated Email</I></strong></td></tr>"; 
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>";
        $sendEmail = mail('info@dffd.co.uk','Mdfdft', $message, $headers);
```

When the email get send I see the following in the email
Person Contact Detail: Name: Ø¨ÙŠÙˆÙ… Ø§Ù„Ø£Ù… Ù… Ù„ØªØ± Email: Ø¨ÙŠÙˆÙ… Ø§Ù„Ø£Ù… Ù„ØªØ± City #: Ø¨ÙŠÙˆÙ… Ø¯Ø§Ù„ Ù„ØªØ± Address #: Ø¨ÙŠÙˆÙ… Ø¹Ù„Ù‰ Ø±Øª Ù„ØªØ± Country#: U.A.E.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure if `ISO-8859-1` supports arabic, you might have to use UTF-8 instead (and that means your *entire code*, including headers in HTML/PHP/mail, should be set to UTF-8). I know UTF-8 supports it anyway.

Comment: You need to change the character set, as stated above ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Qirel said:

> I'm not sure if ISO-8859-1 supports arabic, you might have to use
>   UTF-8 instead (and that means your entire code, including headers in
>   HTML/PHP/mail, should be set to UTF-8). I know UTF-8 supports it
>   anyway.

[You can also check this post for confirmation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996475/what-character-encoding-should-i-use-for-a-web-page-containing-mostly-arabic-tex)