# Arabic text (UTF-8) output issue fetching from Oracle Database

Tags: java, windows, oracle, windows-10

At the time of fetching records of a column ("emp_name") in Arabic format from Oracle database table, getting question mark instead of Arabic name (??????) when I fetch records like:
`String emp_name = rs.getString("EMP_NAME");` 
But If I changed the above line like:
 `String emp_name = new String(rs.getString("EMP_NAME").getBytes("UTF-8"));` getting Arabic name perfectly. But in some Arabic names I found garbage characters mentioned below: `"احمد عبدالحليم سي�? ابراهيم محمود"`

How can I eliminate the �? (garbage character)? Is there any Unicode other than UTF-8 which supports the Arabic name perfectly or will I need to modify the above code to solve the issue?

Comment: To my knowledge, utf-8 supports enough arabic characters. I think some connectors might be replaced with the garbage character. You might be good off by iterating through the string and removing that character

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996475/what-character-encoding-should-i-use-for-a-web-page-containing-mostly-arabic-tex

Comment: Is the client fetching the records set up correctly as far a locale?  What platform is the client running on?  Please [edit] your question to include the platform tag such as [windows] and add what software version of the platform is, such as Windows 10.