# Special HTML Characters

Tags: html, character-encoding

Ok, so I want to have the characters from below in my html page. Seems easy, except I can't find the HTML encoding for them.

[image]

Note: I would like to do this without having sized elements, plain ol' text would be fine ^_^.

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see that they have a unicode number of the selected character - at the bottom of the picture ("U+266A: Eighth Note").

Simply use the last portion in a unicode character entity: `&#x266A;` - ♪

If your page is already UTF-8, you can simply paste it in.

Comment: Perfect, I'll except when I can

Answer (score 4):

Try encoding it as `&#x2588;` - that should do the trick!

Answer (score 3):

In a UTF-8 encoded page, just copy and paste them as-is.

Otherwise, use the number that the dialog gives you for each character, e.g. `&#x266A;`

However, when working with rather exotic characters, be very wary of font support. See e.g. this question for background: [Unicode support in Web standard fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778492/unicode-support-in-web-standard-fonts)

[This page](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/miscellaneous_symbols.html) gives some information about support for the characters you want to use. They seem to be relatively well supported, but a test on Linux and Mac machines won't hurt.

Comment: I just want to add that most webframeworks (e.g. PHP) deliver UTF-8 encoded HTML if you save the template as UTF-8 encoded. You should use an editor that uses this as default encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one [comprehensive entity reference](http://nivas.hr/html-entity/). If you want to convert symbols into their entity counterparts, I suggest using this [converter](http://www.texaswebdevelopers.com/examples/xmlentities/xml_entities.asp).

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use hexadecimal reference. ( it's easy dont worry :) )

for example, the first character you have highlighted in red got ascii value of 175, which is AF in hex.

So in short you can encode it using %AF, and so on...

is it clear mate? Let me know if you need further explanation or help about this :)

Edit: my post is meant for url encoding.