# HTML - star character in html source code

Tags: html, character

I want to have in my `<title>` tag a star character (`&starf;`). It's not a problem to put `&starf` or `&#9733;` but when I put something like this in html code, when I view source code , of website I see real html code. I want to see star in source code. Is it possible - I can see it here: http://www.kabinysanitarne.pl/

Anybody knows how can I do this? :)

Comment: Special characters in `title` elements are often displayed wrong, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865808/title-utf-8-on-html (This is independent of how you enter the characters there.)

Answer (score 4):

You type a ★ and ensure that [the character encoding](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset.en.php) of the HTML matches the encoding specified in the HTTP headers (and any meta tags that specify it).