# Need help locating specific Japanese Unicode characters

Tags: html, unicode, character, html-entities, cjk

I am looking for these three Japanese characters in Unicode Katakana:

[image: three Japanese characters]

I found the middle one, but closest matches I can find are:

**⽊ の ⺶**

`&#12106; &#12398; &#11958;`

I was told there will be no exact match because the image I posted is using a different font which is why it looks different, which doesn't seem to make sense to me.

I was using this web page to do a comparison, but came up short:

[https://www.key-shortcut.com/en/writing-systems/ひらがな-japanese/](https://www.key-shortcut.com/en/writing-systems/%E3%81%B2%E3%82%89%E3%81%8C%E3%81%AA-japanese/)

Does unicode exist for these characters? If so, what are the codes?

I understand how to encode them. I am simply looking for the unicode and coming up short. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6280454/62576 should address your question about fonts.

Comment: Left one looks like[`&#26412`](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=672c) - [本](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9C%AC). Right one looks like [`&#32654`](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=7f8e) - [美](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%BE%8E).

Comment: Arigatōgozaimashita! @showdev if you could post that as an answer, I can close this out as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe they are:

```
&#26412;
&#12398;
&#32654;
```

[本](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9C%AC) [の](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%AE) [美](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%BE%8E)

I used [this tool](https://kanji.sljfaq.org/) to help identify hand-drawn characters.
Also see: [672c](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=672c), [306e](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=306e), and [7f8e](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=7f8e).