# Unwanted "&#number" string in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, display

I work on a prestashop and I got a big display problem.

Instead of display some icons, I got a string like : **&#61573** ; like this picture :

[image: Bug]

HTML Code :

```
<i class="icon-cogs icon-2x icon-light"></i>
```

I have no idea where does this bug come from.

If anyone have an idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: can you provide relevant html code?

Comment: Missing iconfont maybe? Can you check if the iconfont is present? How does it look if you inspect the &#61573 thing

Answer (score 0):

See this - [link](http://unicode-table.com/en/F085/)
Try to add ";" in the end- `&#61573;`

So it will looks like this icon - (`&#61573;`) and not like this &#61573 (`&#61573`)

Comment: There is a `;` at the end

Comment: Oh, I see, so maybe your browser do not support this special character.

Comment: I use chrome in his last version and I tried with another browser

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039354/support-for-unicode-by-browser

Comment: It a matter of font (I think), I open the link in my answer in Firefox and in chrome and I got different results.