# Unicode in <button> is not rendered properly on Safari 5.1 (Windows)

Tags: html, windows, unicode, safari

in Safari 5.1/Windows XP, the unicode arrow in the button element is not shown. `<span>` is working fine.

```
<span>▼</span>
<button>▼</button>
```

Screenshot:
http://cl.ly/image/1T0J1X10141A

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/christianhaller/nTvjU/1/

Any hints to fix this?

further information: IE8 on the same OS has no problems with the unicode character

Comment: looks like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241519/webkit-css-content-unicode-bug has the answer, there is a bug

Comment: @Mark, that question is about a related issue but not the same, and the answer is about CSS escapes; here the character appears as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a font problem. It does not exist in Safari 5.1.7 on Windows 7, but I was able to reproduce it in Safari 5.1.7 in a virtual Windows XP. Instead of the triangle character, a small rectangle appears, a common indicator of a missing glyph.

Apparently, on Windows XP, Safari uses some fixed font (seems to be Microsoft Sans Serif) for `button` elements and fails to look for other fonts when it encounters a character that is not present in that font. Luckily, this can be fixed by specifying a font that does contain it. If you prefer to have `button` elements rendered in Microsoft Sans Serif in general, it suffices to specify a fallback font in CSS:

```
button { font-family: Microsoft Sans Serif, Arial }
```

[Quite a few fonts](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25bc/fontsupport.htm) contain the triangle character, so there are many options. And you might wish to make some of them the primary font for `button` elements, not just as fallback font.