# Safari on the iPhone cant display escaped unicode character

Tags: iphone, html, css, unicode, pseudo-class

I created a pseudo-class (`:before`) for my class and set it's `content` parameter to `\0027F6` which is the escaped unicode character for `&rarr;` (right arrow).

On Google Chrome on my Mac everything is rendering fine but I've tested it on Safari with my iPhone and it just shows the square sign and not an arrow.

Please help

Comment: It was a webkit bug. This will help you. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241519/webkit-css-content-unicode-bug