# Escaped Unicode Character in :before{content} Not Recognized by Mobile Webkit

Tags: css, mobile-webkit

I am using `:before{ content: "\1F4C4"; }` to insert Entypo webfont icons before my links.  The icons aren't loading on mobile webkit.  Instead, a diamond with a ? inside shows in their place.

Oddly enough, I don't have this problem in any desktop browser, including webkit.  Also, the same icons loaded via `<a >&#128222;</a>` show just fine in mobile webkit.

Comment: A URL of a test page would help. Do other Entypo icons work?

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with a bug in Webkit. I noticed that it only affects unicode with more then 4 characters. See the following answer for further details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10641785/2114896