# Glyphicons appear as empty squares

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I am in a near identical situation to this poster: [Glyphicons rendering as empty box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678638/glyphicons-rendering-as-empty-box)

I have locally hosted glyph-icons and bootstrap, but my file structure is correct, and my network shows I am receiving 200 OK for the glyphicons.  It works if I use an external library, such as http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/.  But I would prefer to use my local glyphicons, any ideas?

Comment: Are your locally hosted glyph icons on the same domain? If they are on a separate domain, even locally, you will run into cross domain issues.

Answer (score 0):

More likely than not, either the file is corrupt (least likely), the (local) file path is incorrect (except you're getting a 200 which means it should be), or you may need to change the HTML charset to unicode. Try:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: Double-check your class names as well.

Answer (score 0):

Any spelling mistake in "glyphicons" also causes the icons to be square