# Glyphicons with Bootstrap won't show with <h:outputStylesheet> but with <link ...>

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jsf-2.2, glyphicons

I think a lot of you know about twitter-bootstrap which makes it so easy to design "pretty" websites. I'm recently developing a JSF web application in Netbeans.
Everything except of the glyphicons.

In the header part of your website you will include bootstrap via

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.min.css"></h:outputStylesheet>
```

if you use jsf or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

if don't use jsf.

The weird think is that the glyphicons are empty squares like in this question:
[Glyphicons rendering as empty box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678638/glyphicons-rendering-as-empty-box)

I already checked with view-source with my browser and both rendered CSS have the same content.

```
    <head id="j_idt2">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/WWHY/faces/javax.faces.resource/bootstrap.min.css?ln=css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/WWHY/faces/javax.faces.resource/styles.css?ln=css" />
        <title>WWHY IT Support Center</title>
        <script src="resources/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Maybe you guys know why  doesn't work for the glyphicons.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the same as with font-awesome. Check [How to use Font Awesome from webjars.org with JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891768/how-to-use-font-awesome-3-2-1-from-webjars-org-with-jsf)

Although in th FA case there already was a jsf specific css