# Why do only some Bootstrap glyph icons work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the following code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
<body>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-glass"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

The first two icons display perfectly but there is some error with the wrench. Based on the documentation here:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/

'wrench' should be a valid icon. How can I get the wrench to display?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There wasn't a `glyphicon-wrench` in 3.0.0..

http://www.bootply.com/rvIujXrVQ7

But there is now..

http://www.bootply.com/WwpyWuQTr3

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're using old Android and are encountering https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10106 , which was [fixed in Bootstrap v3.0.1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/10778).

The underlying cause is explained in this SO thread: [WebKit CSS content Unicode bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241519/webkit-css-content-unicode-bug)